# Resource Controller methods with model as parameter not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

As in the basic Laracasts.com tutorial (Laracast 5.7 from scratch) I'm trying to use the following methods `public function show(prototypes $prototypes)` parameter to construct a view. However my view is created correctly but `$prototypes` is null.

The route works well(`/prototypes/1/edit`) and I ensured that a `prototype` object with the id 1 exists.
I found some older solution which stated to use something like `(integer $id)` as parameter but this leads to some more code. It should work like this:

Controller:

```php
public function edit(prototypes $prototypes)
{
    //
    return view('prototypes.edit', compact('prototypes'));
}
```

According to *Laracast From Scratch* this should work.

Do you know how I could fix this?

What mechanism is behind this that the `prototypes.edit` method knows how to use the correct parameter?

Comment: Please can you show route declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the [Implicit Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding) to works the *injected variable name* should match the *route parameter name*, in your case I think that your parameter name could be `{prototype}`, you can verify it by issuing the command `php artisan route:list` in the console.

If that is true you have to change the variable name to `$prototype` (please note the singular) in your controller function to match the parameter name `{prototype}`, like this:

```php
public function edit(prototypes $prototype)
{
   return view('prototypes.edit', compact('prototype'));
}
```

Update: BTW the laravel convention on Model's name is singular camel case, in your case your Model should be named `Prototype` not `prototypes`, i.e.:

```php
public function edit(Prototype $prototype)
{
   return view('prototypes.edit', compact('prototype'));
}
```

Comment: Great! This part 'the injected variable name should match the route parameter name' solve my problem, bro. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to inject the **Prototypes** model into the controller variable `$prototypes`, Laravel is expecting a matched name from the route to the input of the method.  So in your routing, this:

```
 /prototypes/1/edit
```

Needs to be

```
 /prototypes/{prototypes}/edit
```

in order for the edit method to inject the correct instance of your prototypes model.