# Laravel 5.8 Edit function returns #connection: null and #table: null when i dump my model

Tags: php, laravel, null, connection, edit

web.php

```
Route::resource('/facilities','FacilitieController')->middleware('auth');
```

Controller

```
public function edit( Facilitie $facilitie)
{
    dd($facilitie);
    return view("/admin.facilities.edit", [
        "tableName" => "facilities",
        "facilitie" => $facilitie
    ]);
}
```

[Result when i  dd ($facilitie)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G9Z3.png)

Comment: Please include code where you called `show()` method of your route. Did you pass `$facilitie` object to your route when you called the show method?

Comment: web.php

@zlatan i don't have show method. but please find below all the code in web.php
also please note that pages is working fine  ( create, store , edit , update ).

Route::resource('/facilities','FacilitieController')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('/facility_galleries','Facility_gallerieController')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('/pages','PageController')->middleware('auth');

Comment: My mistake, I meant `edit()` function. Where do you call it and pass parameters? Seems like your `$facilitie` variable is null, hence empty `Facilitie` class is returned.

Comment: In laravel when you use Route::resource like below
Route::resource('/facilities','FacilitieController')->middleware('auth');
by default when you send a request in url facilities/1/edit by default it calls edit  function

Comment: @zlatan 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Actions Handled By Resource Controller
Verb URI Action Route Name
GET /photos index photos.index
GET /photos/create create photos.create
POST /photos store photos.store
GET /photos/{photo} show photos.show
GET /photos/{photo}/edit edit photos.edit
PUT/PATCH /photos/{photo} update photos.update
DELETE /photos/{photo} destroy photos.destroy

Comment: You can check this solution as well from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/57617041/6307126

Answer (score 3):

Problem was that in edit function i put    (Facilitie   $facilitie ) and it must be (Facilitie   $facility ).

i assumed that laravel will just remove the( s from the variable ) but it seams that it transform plural with (ies)to ( Y )

i figure out the problem after i use php artisan route:list and this gives me to where i should look .

[please check image below in white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK7PZ.png)